# Phonegap Older Build to Newer Build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-3

Currently I have had a project handed off to me built on cordova 2.0 and only Android.

I would like to get this project on the new build 3.4, though i fear there will be issues.

As well i would like to be able to build IOS version very simply.

How can i build this current project on 3.4 without messing it up or making any bugs worse?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of the application.  Since Cordova 2.x is no longer supported, I would take everything out of the assets/www directory and save it somewhere, then create a new project using the Cordova CLI and put the saved files in the www directory of that project.  Once that is done, create an iOS and Android project, and see what breaks.

It does help to know which features the previous application was using, since this will be required when porting such an old app to Cordova 3.4.x.  Here's a link to the CLI guide to help get started.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface